# GPU Stops Working Rendering Smoke

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation, gpu

I am working on a simple smoke sim using cycles, and was rendering fine on the GPU. Suddenly, blender crashes and when I reopen blender the GPU no longer renders smoke.

I have tried opening an older version of the project, and still the GPU does not render the smoke. Same story after restarting computer, emptying cache, re baking the sim, and updating GPU drivers.

The simulation still renders fine on the CPU, and all the other objects/materials render fine with the GPU.

This has now happened to me on multiple projects, and is very frustrating as blender crashes all the time while rendering decent fire animations on my cpu. I'm not sure why that is.

I am running Blender 2.78, and here are my computer specs:

CPU - Intel i7 - 5930K CPU @ 3.50GHz
32 GB RAM
GPU - GeForce GTX 980 Ti (x2)

Running Win10 pro 64 bit

And, in blender under user preferences I have the compute device set to:
CUDA
GeForce GTX 980 Ti (2x)

And have the device set to "GPU Compute" in the render tab.

Any thoughts, or anyone experience a similar problem?

Comment: It used to be (and I think it still is) that in order to render smoke with GPU the feature set must be changed to 'Experimental' instead of 'Supported'.  It's right below the drop down for GPU/CPU.  Crashing during rendering may also be due to memory.  try baking at a lower resolution, or a shorter duration and see what happens.

Comment: I have the feature set changed to "experimental", and still don't get anything to show up in the rendered view. 

Weirdly, when I open a new project, and try to make a new smoke sim it works fine when set to GPU. However I already had all the objects/textures/lighting done so if i can avoid remaking the scene it would be nice.

Comment: I am wondering if somehow some settings where changed which threw it off? 

Originally the simulation was working fine, then it crashed while rendering, and after the crash I was unable to view any smoke whatsoever using the gpu to render, (including creating entirely new sims inside that project). This makes me think somehow due to the crash some setting was changed that is crucial to gpu rendering smoke?

Comment: can you even see the smoke sim in the viewport, if not you will need to re-bake the sim.  Also I should mention that you if you didn't bake it, and just hit alt a, you should definitely, 100%, bake it.

Comment: Try experimental and turn off denoising.